# Is there any point to having a power plane for a single device?

Tags: power-supply, power, analog

Let's say I have a power supply that is powering only a single sensitive opamp. That opamp only has a single power and ground pin.

Is there any point to having a power plane for that power supply, or would it be sufficient to have a fat power trace leading to the device and its bypass caps?

Comment: **current return path**. You don't only have to care about the supply of the opamp, but also (and probably even more so) about the currents that flow around, into and out of it.

Comment: I'd definitely look at the whole current loop. I don't see why using a traces for power wouldn't work, it's just I've never seen it done like that. It almost seems that with sensitive circuits using traces for power/return could better isolate the currents with carefully careful planning.

Comment: @sgdsgyhetwaraw I've done it for the odd component that requires one different voltage and an LDO just for itself.

Comment: Well, then you're not looking very closely so far: Say, your opamp outputs a current \$I\$ into a resistor a bit away. Where does the return path for that current go, *specifically*, i.e. where does it end and start? (You really don't need a whole plane, but you'll have one return trace below *each and every trace that might carry any signal*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done a half dozen simple but moderately high frequency (50-100 MHz) opamps on two layer boards with no dedicated power planes and never had a serious problem that a power plane would have fixed. Provided you route the power lines carefully, that you keep as solid as possible a ground under the power and signal traces and the board is simple enough you can make it work.

I think it usually isn't done because four layer boards are only a little more expensive but are easier to work with and much more versatile, especially if you want to have more than just an opamp.